# Why does passing the generic result of a fallible function as a generic parameter infer ()? Shouldn't it be ambiguous?

Tags: generics, rust

In the following code, I have a `make_t()` function that returns some generic `T` in a `Result`. The returned value from that (after propagating the error) is used to create a `MyType` using a `From` implementation. As far as I know, this should be ambiguous since there is no hint that one particular intermediate type, `String` or `()` or something else, should be chosen and yet it selects `()` without error ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d3ea8992bcf9fe5344a567d7af550fec)):

```
struct Error;
struct MyType;

impl From<String> for MyType {
    fn from(_: String) -> Self {
        println!("used From<String>");
        Self
    }
}

impl From<()> for MyType {
    fn from(_: ()) -> Self {
        println!("used From<()>");
        Self
    }
}

fn make_t<T: Default>() -> Result<T, Error> {
    Ok(T::default())
}

impl MyType {
    fn new() -> Result<Self, Error> {
        Ok(MyType::from(make_t()?))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _ = MyType::new();
}
```

```
used From<()>
```

What's even more confusing, the compiler seems very confident it *should* use `()` because if I remove the `From<()>` altogether, it does yield an error ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8ca75c3e3fa3807fe25b5ce3ead6ba85)):

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `MyType: From<()>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:17:25
   |
17 |         Ok(MyType::from(make_t()?))
   |            ------------ ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<()>` is not implemented for `MyType`
   |            |
   |            required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
   = help: the trait `From<String>` is implemented for `MyType`
```

One piece of the puzzle is definitely the `Result` since converting `make_t` to be infallible will make it ambiguous as expected ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=81e122bbf2741de182a2a2e1eef06883)):

```
fn make_t<T: Default>() -> T {
    T::default()
}

impl MyType {
    fn new() -> Result<Self, Error> {
        Ok(MyType::from(make_t()))
    }
}
```

```
error[E0283]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:24:25
   |
24 |         Ok(MyType::from(make_t()))
   |            ------------ ^^^^^^ cannot infer type of the type parameter `T` declared on the function `make_t`
   |            |
   |            required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
note: multiple `impl`s satisfying `MyType: From<_>` found
  --> src/main.rs:4:1
   |
4  | impl From<String> for MyType {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...
11 | impl From<()> for MyType {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: and more `impl`s found in the following crates: `core`:
           - impl<T> From<!> for T;
           - impl<T> From<T> for T;
help: consider specifying the generic argument
   |
24 |         Ok(MyType::from(make_t::<T>()))
   |                               +++++
```

Of course using a turbofish to specify the type works to avoid `()` (i.e. `make_t::<String>()`) but I feel that should be enforced regardless.

Can anyone explain this? Why does the compiler choose `()` when it should be ambiguous?

Comment: It appears to be down to the `?` operator, since `.ok().unwrap()` gives rise to the expected type ambiguity.  Desugaring to a match does not however; I wonder whether the `Err` arm of the match, which should have `!` type, is (erroneously) being coerced to `()` instead.

Comment: Very interesting. Did you already report this in the language issue tracker? If so, what's their opinion?

Comment: Just doing `let _ = make_t();` gives an ambiguity error, as expected.

Comment: @eggyal That's possible. In the work to stabilize the never type, there are some cases where we give `()` instead of `()`. I don't know the exact rules, though.

Comment: This may be related to the incompleteness mentioned in this [Rustc Trait System Refactor Initiative Update](https://blog.rust-lang.org/inside-rust/2023/07/17/trait-system-refactor-initiative.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug.

There is [issue #94902: The Try trait causes str::parse to infer the unit type ()](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/94902) that reports this. From comments there, this appears to be the behavior of the `?` operator since it was introduced in 1.13. However, I can not find anything in the original [RFC #0243](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0243-trait-based-exception-handling.md) or the accompanying issues and PRs to suggest this behavior is intentional (though my search was not exhaustive).

However, there is a link to `!` (the [never](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.never.html) type) as suggested by @eggyal and @ChayimFriedman in the comments. Before its introduction, diverging blocks (like one with a `return` that `?` will generate) would fallback to `()` (the unit type). At one point it was stabilized, but that was reverted due to this "fallback" type mechanism being incomplete. I'm unsure exactly how it manifests, but the behavior above is probably a residual effect of that underlying problem. See the [never type tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/35121) and linked issues and PRs for more information.

Apparently this kind of fallback to `()` should trigger a warning but there is [another bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/51125) that means it hasn't since 1.24, and it was designed at least partially to catch the problem above. I was able to confirm an older version of the compiler used to emit an error with my code:

```
error: code relies on type inference rules which are likely to change
   --> src/main.rs:255:25
    |
255 |         Ok(MyType::from(make_some_t()?))
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: #[deny(resolve_trait_on_defaulted_unit)] on by default
    = warning: this was previously accepted by the compiler but is being phased out; it will become a hard error in a future release!
    = note: for more information, see issue #39216 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/39216>
```

Given that the oddity with `?` took so long to be reported by an outside user, it is clear to me this is not a common issue. Hopefully it will be addressed in the future by stabilization of the never type or some other effort.